# Are there any noise cancellation algorithm used in wireless communication? if so in which layer?

Tags: communication, wireless, digital-communications

I understand that there are 7 layers in the OSI model. I would like to know is there any noise cancellation algorithm used in wireless communication? If so in which layer is it used? I am looking for a reference where I can know more about the algorithm used related to noise cancellation (not other algorithms, only noise cancellation). I understand the existence of channel estimation but I am not looking for those. In other words, is there a blind noise reduction algorithm used that is not related to channel estimation? It may be that there is no such algorithm, and if so I would like to know?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1801/1801.01111.pdf

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 thank you for the references.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 not sure if those algorithms are actually used in existing wireless communication.

Comment: @Creator, the paper doesn’t go into that, but most noise enters the system at the physical layer, so it makes the most sense to remove it at the physical layer. Once each symbol is detected, the receiver (physical layer) decides how to interpret that symbol, and from that point forward, any noise that results in bit errors must be dealt with using error correction coding (data link layer). I believe the wavelet transform and adaptive filters are both commonly used in wireless channels, and both are done on the physical layer.

Comment: @Ryan May I ask if you know the kind of algorithm that is being used ? Any references to understand those algorithms, or those algorithms are secret for the companies who deal with physical layers?

Comment: The Wavelet Transform and LMS adaptive filter are well understood in the signal processing world and there’s a lot of information you can find on them on the internet and in textbooks. How to apply them to your problem is a different story. The wavelet transform really only applies in specific applications, I would suggest reading the references in that paper. The LMS Adaptive filter is more straightforward, and it was developed specifically for the purpose of noise cancellation. You can probably find a detailed description of the algorithm on Google.

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-161-signal-processing-continuous-and-discrete-fall-2008/lecture-notes/lecture_25.pdf

Comment: 'Noise' is by definition unknown and not correlated to anything, so a 'noise reduction' process is by definition impossible. But sometimes other things get called this. For instance in CDMA, there is a process to estimate the data transmissions of unwanted stations and subtract this 'noise' from the wanted code. Many other 'de-noising' algorithms are in fact 'signal enhancing' algorithms, using known facts about the signal and its correlations. They have the desired effect of improving the SNR before any detection bakes the errors into the demodulated signal.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thank you for your interest in this question. May I request your opinion on the edited question? I have added a very simple scenario (not demodulation) just for understanding. The algorithm for noise reduction is not the usual convolution filter. Is the result good? By the way the algorithm does not assume the source position in time.

Comment: _" Consider we have three sinusoidal and noise on a channel."_ - What is the point of having 3 sine waves?

Comment: @Creator Five sample moving average is trivially a low pass filter, and yes, it can be expressed as a convolution filter. We don't usually bother to call a technique 'noise reduction' until we've done all the simple frequency domain filtering we can to reduce out of band noise, while keeping inband signal. Filtering inband noise is then usually called 'Matched Filtering'.

Comment: @BruceAbbott As I commented to Neil_UK it is just an example of possible noise reduction, where we do not know what frequencies to expect or the signal.

Comment: @Creator If you know the signal, then matched filter, aka correlation, is exactly what you should use. If you do not know what frequencies to expect, then a fdrequency dependent filter like moving average, is exactly what you should not use. I think you need to do signal processing 101, if nothing else to get your terminology in line with the rest of the DSP planet.

Comment: @Neil_UK, We do not know the signal so matched filter is not possible. It is just an example of a noise reduction of signal and noise. Here we do not know the expected frequencies as well. OMG, what error I made in my earlier comment. I did not write both no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layers higher than physical layer handle symbols, there's no such thing as noise, only symbols that can be right or they can be wrong due wrong decision. Error detection & correction by having redundant data in the symbol stream can be used (and is also used in practice) to decide what data was most probably actually transmitted. But that's not noise reduction, it's algorithmic reduction of the effects of the noise.

Seriously, one cannot reduce noise without knowing how it differs from the actual signal. Imagine your actual signal is generated in your program with the rand function and the sines present disturbing extras. Separating the wanted signal needs totally opposite actions than extracting the sines. If the receiver doesn't know how noise and actual signal differ there's no way to separate them.

Your windowed average is a form of low pass filtering. It can reduce a part of the noise if the noise covers wider frequency band than the wanted signal, but I wouldn't call it especially effective. Bandpass filters tuned to the frequencies of the sines can be much better assuming the sine bursts are long enough.

There are numerous adaptive methods which try to guess what's noise. The oldest one is gating by level. The signal is silenced fully if its level is below a certain treshold. The treshold is often decided by assuming the signal is mostly plain noise and the level changes to higher mean there's something transmitted.

When DSP became available for everyman in PCs about 25 years ago the same base idea was adapted into audio denoising as a highly refined variation. I feed to the algorithm a  sample of plain noise (generated maybe by poor mic amps, tape recorders and air conditioning). The algorithm calculates the spectrum of the sample with high resolution. The number of the separate frequency bands can be several hundreds. The measured levels in the separate bands are considered as the noise floor.

Then the audio signal is divided to the same frequency bands (=it's spectrum is calculated) and all those bands which are not louder than the noise floor are silenced. Some guessing is still needed. The length of the processing chunks must be shorter if there's detected a sharp attack in the audio. The algorithm must detect them. Too long processing chunk can silence a short peak sound because it doesn't affect enough to the average power level in any band and too short one reduces too much the achievable frequency selectivity.

The noise sample denoising method is available in all audio workstations and audio cleaning utilities. It's effectiveness against tape and mic preamp hiss can appear incredible for a person who hears it first time.

The noise sample method is useless if the noise isn't stationary. Adaptive methods which analyze the behaviour of the noise environment are developed. I must skip them due the lack of knowledge. But someone still must have programmed to them the base criteria how to see what's the wanted signal and what's noise.

It's easy to believe that some feedback from the data error detection is useful. =>> I guess that the cleverness of noise reduction really could happen a step higher than in the physical level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.